# Access parent prop from child

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to implement a simple router on a page. I have a parent class which controls which view is loaded **HutDBStatsRouter** and 2 child classes **HutDBStats** and **HutDBPlayerView**. HutDBStats contains a ListView with a TouchableOpacity that when clicked needs to render HutDBPlayerView. I'm running into an issue I believe because HutDBStats has its own props, but I can't figure out how to properly pass it to the parent class HutDBStatsRouter.

For testing purposes I setup the same scenario in HutDBPlayerView and had it render HutDBStats (it worked fine), but it wont work when I have HutDBStats try to render HutDBPlayerView.

The code is fairly large so I cut out any unnecessary information. The error I am getting is **cannot read property of 'changeComponent' of undefined**.

```
export default class HutDBStatsRouter extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          componentSelected: 'One',
        }
    }
    changeComponent = (component) =>{
        this.setState({componentSelected: component});
    }
    renderComponent(component) {
        if(component == 'Two') {
            return <HutDBStats changeComponent={this.changeComponent} />
        } else if(component == 'One') {
            return <HutDBPlayerView changeComponent={this.changeComponent} />
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                {this.renderComponent(this.state.componentSelected)}
            </View>
        );
    }
}

class HutDBPlayerView extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.changeComponent('Two') }>
                    <Text>Go back to ListView</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

class HutDBStats extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
         super(props);
         this.state = {
             source      : [],
             dataSource : new ListView.DataSource({ rowHasChanged: (row1, row2) => row1 !== row2, }),
             loaded     : false,
             page       : PAGE_LOAD_AMT,
             search     : '',
         };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
         this.fetchData(API_PATH + '&page=0',true, false);
    }

    .......
    .......

    renderList(d) {
        return (
             <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.changeComponent('Two') }>
                ...
              </TouchableOpacity>
          );
    }
 }
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. I am very new to react-native.

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be that the constructor is missing in HutDBPlayerView.

```js
class HutDBPlayerView extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.changeComponent('Two') }>
                    <Text>Go back to ListView</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

If you intend this to be a stateless component, you can even code it like so:

```js
function HutDBPlayerView (props){
  return (
      <View>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => props.changeComponent('Two') }>
              <Text>Go back to ListView</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This didn't work but I was able to resolve the problem by using: changeComponent = this.props.changeComponent(bind) before rending the ListView.